# Extracting text from scanned PDF without saving the scan as a new file image

Tags: python, ocr

I would like to extract text from scanned PDFs.
My "test" code is as follows:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL import Image

converted_scan = convert_from_path('test.pdf', 500)

for i in converted_scan:
    i.save('scan_image.png', 'png')
    
text = image_to_string(Image.open('scan_image.png'))
with open('scan_text_output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(text.replace('\n\n', '\n'))
```

I would like to know if there is a way to extract the content of the image directly from the object `converted_scan`, without saving the scan as a new "physical" image file on the disk?

Basically, I would like to skip this part:

```
for i in converted_scan:
    i.save('scan_image.png', 'png')
```

I have a few thousands scans to extract text from. Although all the generated new image files are not particularly heavy, it's not negligible and I find it a bit overkill.

**EDIT**

Here's a slightly different, more compact approach than Colonder's answer, based on [this post](https://pythontips.com/2016/02/25/ocr-on-pdf-files-using-python/). For .pdf files with many pages, it might be worth adding a progress bar to each loop using e.g. the `tqdm` module.

```
from wand.image import Image as w_img
from PIL import Image as p_img
import pyocr.builders
import regex, pyocr, io

infile = 'my_file.pdf'
tool = pyocr.get_available_tools()[0]
tool = tools[0]
req_image = []
txt = ''

# to convert pdf to img and extract text
with w_img(filename = infile, resolution = 200) as scan:
    image_png = scan.convert('png')
    for i in image_png.sequence:
        img_page = w_img(image = i)
        req_image.append(img_page.make_blob('png'))
    for i in req_image:
        content = tool.image_to_string(
            p_img.open(io.BytesIO(i)),
            lang = tool.get_available_languages()[0],
            builder = pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
        )
        txt += content

# to save the output as a .txt file
with open(infile[:-4] + '.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    full_txt = regex.sub(r'\n+', '\n', txt)
    outfile.write(full_txt)
```

Comment: Please include the `convert_from_path` function in your question

Comment: @Nick [here](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image/blob/master/pdf2image/pdf2image.py#L37) you can see that `convert_from_path` just calls `pdftocairo` or `pdftoppm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE MAY 2021**
I realized that although `pdf2image` is simply calling a subprocess, one doesn't have to save images to subsequently OCR them. What you can do is just simply (you can use `pytesseract` as OCR library as well)

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

for img in convert_from_path("some_pdf.pdf", 300):
    txt = tool.image_to_string(img,
                               lang=lang,
                               builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder())
```

**EDIT**: you can also try and use [`pdftotext`](https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/) library

`pdf2image` is a simple wrapper around `pdftoppm` and `pdftocairo`. It internally does nothing more but calls subprocess. This script should do what you want, but you need a [`wand`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.8/) library as well as [`pyocr`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/pyocr) (I think this is a matter of preference, so feel free to use any library for text extraction you want).

```
from PIL import Image as Pimage, ImageDraw
from wand.image import Image as Wimage
import sys
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

import pyocr
import pyocr.builders

def _convert_pdf2jpg(in_file_path: str, resolution: int=300) -> Pimage:
    """
    Convert PDF file to JPG

    :param in_file_path: path of pdf file to convert
    :param resolution: resolution with which to read the PDF file
    :return: PIL Image
    """
    with Wimage(filename=in_file_path, resolution=resolution).convert("jpg") as all_pages:
        for page in all_pages.sequence:
            with Wimage(page) as single_page_image:
                # transform wand image to bytes in order to transform it into PIL image
                yield Pimage.open(BytesIO(bytearray(single_page_image.make_blob(format="jpeg"))))

tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
if len(tools) == 0:
    print("No OCR tool found")
    sys.exit(1)
# The tools are returned in the recommended order of usage
tool = tools[0]
print("Will use tool '%s'" % (tool.get_name()))
# Ex: Will use tool 'libtesseract'

langs = tool.get_available_languages()
print("Available languages: %s" % ", ".join(langs))
lang = langs[0]
print("Will use lang '%s'" % (lang))
# Ex: Will use lang 'fra'
# Note that languages are NOT sorted in any way. Please refer
# to the system locale settings for the default language
# to use.
for img in _convert_pdf2jpg("some_pdf.pdf"):
    txt = tool.image_to_string(img,
                               lang=lang,
                               builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder())
```